# Habilitar y deshabilitar boton al validar radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radiobutton

Tengo un Formulario con 4 input de tipo radio y un boton para enviar el formulario el cual lo trabaje con jquery.

1- Logre hacer check y uncheck en los radio button pero el codigo es algo extenso y me gustaria poder tenerla mas simplificado.

2- El boton de enviar debe habilitarse cuando al menos 1 de los radio button este check y deshabilitarse cuando los radio button esten uncheck o se haga check y uncheck y todos los radio button queden uncheck.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" class="radio1 r" value="0">
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio2 r" value="0">
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio3 r" value="0">
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio4 r" value="0">
<br>
<br>
<button class="btn" disabled="disabled">
Enter
</button>
```

JS-Jquery

```
var radio1 = false;
$(".radio1").click(function () {
        if (radio1 == false) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            $(this).prop("value", "1");
            radio1= true;

        }

        else if (radio1 == true) {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            $(this).prop("value", "0");            
            radio1= false;            
        }
    });

var radio2 = false;
    $(".radio2").click(function () {
        if (radio2 == false) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            $(this).prop("value", "1");
            radio2= true;
        }

        else if (radio2 == true) {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            radio2= false;
        }
    });

    var radio3 = false;
    $(".radio3").click(function () {
        if (radio3 == false) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            $(this).prop("value", "1");
            radio3= true;
        }

        else if (radio3 == true) {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            radio3= false;
        }
    });

    var radio4 = false;
    $(".radio4").click(function () {
        if (radio4 == false) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            $(this).prop("value", "1");
            radio4= true;
        }

        else if (radio4 == true) {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            radio4= false;
        }
    });

function calcscore(){
    var score = 0;
    $(".r:checked").each(function(){
        score+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);

         if( score > 0 )
          $('.btn').prop('disabled',false);
        else
          $('.btn').prop('disabled',true);
    });
    $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
}
$().ready(function(){
    $(".r").change(function(){
        calcscore()
    });
});
```

pueden verlo en ejecucion [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/alejoacevedor1/xbv25s47/1/)

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: El propósito específico de un grupo de botones radio es para que el usuario solo pueda elegir uno. Los checkboxes aportan el funcionamiento que buscas aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que forzar un radio button a que se comporte como un checkbox a través de código js, no es lo correcto. Tomé tu código y lo ajusté para usar `checkbox` en vez de `radio` como type, así te ahorras de poner todos esos `$(".radio").click` que no serían necesarios. Aparte le agregué valores distintos a los inputs, para ver cómo se comporta el código. Revisa además los cambios en la función `calcscore`.

```js
function calcscore(){
    let score = 0;
    let checked = $(".r:checked");
    if(checked.length > 0) {
      checked.each(function(){
          score+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
           if( score > 0 )
            $('.btn').prop('disabled',false);
          else
            $('.btn').prop('disabled',true);
      });    
    } else {
      $('.btn').prop('disabled',true);
    }
    $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
}
$().ready(function(){
    $(".r").change(function(){
        calcscore()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="r" value="0">0
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="r" value="1">1
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="r" value="2">2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="r" value="3">3
<br>
<input name="sum">
<br>

<button class="btn" disabled="disabled">
Enter
</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, toda la razon en que es mejor emplear los checkbox en vez de radio